# How can I do a multiple-level eager load in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, orm, sqlalchemy

I have many `C`s in a `B` and many `B`s in an `A`, and I have backref relationships defined. What I want to do is something like:

```
a = A.query().options(subqueryload(A.b).subsubqueryload(B.c)
```

How should this be done?

Answer (score 7):

Straight from the documentation of [`subqueryload`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.subqueryload):

```
qry = query(A).options(subqueryload(A.b).subqueryload(B.c))
```